# Struggling in updating data in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a datagridview and it is bound to a database. When i click one of its cell to update its value, actually what happens is that the value of that particular cell is updated but the values of the same row is also updated to null. What do i do so that the values of the same row does not updates to null but it remains as they are?

My Code :

```
int quantityColumnIndex = 0;
string particularColumnIndex = "";
int rateColumnIndex = 0;

private void buttonUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  {
    string SQL = "Update OrderLineItems set Quantity = " + quantityColumnIndex +
                 ", Particular = '" + particularColumnIndex +
                 "', Rate = " + rateColumnIndex + " where OrderLineItems.Id = " + Id;
    result = dm.ExecuteActionQuery(SQL);
  }

  if (result > 0)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully", "Update Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
  }
}

private void dataGridViewOrderDetails_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
  {
    quantityColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridViewOrderDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value);
  }

  if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
  {
    particularColumnIndex = dataGridViewOrderDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
  }

  if (e.ColumnIndex == 3)
  {
    rateColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridViewOrderDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value);
  }
}
```

Help required

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Why have you commented out the second line in the block? Why are you casting the `Value` property to `DataGridViewCell`? Help required.

Comment: well,i was working right now on it.. i was trying my level best to do so but couldn`t do so.. i comment those lines which do not work and then erase but i forgot to erase it here.

Comment: @AbidAli [really polite tone] he didn't ask you if it still wasn't working... he asked what do you mean by not norking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void buttonUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((dataGridViewOrderDetails.Rows.Count - 1 > RowCount) == false)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewOrderDetails.RowCount - 1; i++)
                {
                    string SQL = "Update OrderLineItems set Quantity = " + dataGridViewOrderDetails.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value +
                        ", Particular = '" + dataGridViewOrderDetails.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value + "', Rate = " + dataGridViewOrderDetails.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value + " where OrderLineItems.Id = " + dataGridViewOrderDetails.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
                    result = dm.ExecuteActionQuery(SQL);
                }
            }
```

There is a problem in a query. This has been solved :)

Comment: You're going to use ivowiblo's answer but try to steal back the rep bounty... ?

Comment: @Falkreon you are absolutely wrong my friend,
i actually myself sorted out the error and displaying it here and letting people know that this question is solved :)
well i got no issue if some one else steals my rep bounty. because i dont care :)

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to change quantityColumnIndex, particularColumnIndex and rateColumnIndex to nullables and change the query so it doesn't update the columns that weren't changed.

I guess you know which is the row that's being edited. If you don't, then you will have troubles if the user changes the values but selects another row. So, if you know the row, I think the better choice is to change the query to:

```
var row = dataGridViewOrderDetails.Rows[rowNumber];
string SQL = "Update OrderLineItems set Quantity = " + Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value); + ", Particular = '" + row.Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "', Rate = " + Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value)+ " where OrderLineItems.Id = " + Id;
result = dm.ExecuteActionQuery(SQL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to assign a new value ?

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
        {
          dataGridViewOrderDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = 5;
        }
```

However if the datagrid is bound to a datatable you have to update the value in the datatable.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you casting the result of the `Value` property to the `DataGridViewCell` type? The [`Value` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value.aspx) gives you the value of the cell, not the cell itself. The code is wrong; make sure you understand the object model of the `DataGridView` control.

Try the following code instead:

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
{
    // Get a reference to the cell of interest.
    DataGridViewCell quantity = dataGridViewOrderDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

    // Update its value.
    quantity.Value = 100;  // or whatever your new value is
}
```

Comment: my new value is when i edit the cell of the datagridview.. 
how do i write it programatically?

Comment: quantity.Value = dataGridViewOrderDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].toString() ?

Comment: @Abid: I don't understand what that means. When you edit the cell, the value is automatically updated. If you want to set it to an arbitrary value, replace `100` with whatever variable contains your new value.

Comment: Uh, to set the value of one cell equal to the value of another cell, you'd do `cell1.Value = cell2.Value`

Comment: @Abid: Try calling `DataGridView.EndEdit()` or `DataGridView.Invalidate()`. You still haven't told us if your data grid is bound to a database or not. That makes a difference in how you do things. Make sure you've read the documentation for the `DataGridView` control, rather than trying to just blindly grope your way through.

Comment: try doing datagridview1.Refresh();

Answer (score 0):

Can you check whether the same thing happening in your database as well ( changing all values to null except the one you edited).

Check the values of the variables(quantityColumnIndex,particularColumnIndex and rateColumnIndex ) at run time on line "result = dm.ExecuteActionQuery(SQL);".

I think all the values will be null except the one you just edited because you are changing the value of only one variable in dataGridViewOrderDetails_CellValueChanged(..) method. So you need to assign values to all the variables in the dataGridViewOrderDetails_CellValueChanged function.

Comment: Ok. Try now with removing all if statements in dataGridViewOrderDetails_CellValueChanged(...) function.